# Is there yii2 gridView JS manual?

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2

It seems yii2 grid view has own **jQuery events** like `change.yiiGridView` or `keydown.yiiGridView`. Cant find any info about these events. Does this exists ?

Official doc says:

> Note: This section has not been written yet. It should contain
>   explanation of the functionality provided by yii.js:

But people are using this functionsl somehow.

Answer (score 0):

`yiiGridView` in context of `change.yiiGridView` just a namespace, so the events are standart